# Nginx auth_request throttle not respected

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, throttling

I have an nginx config like the following (some details are omitted):

```
http {

  map $request_uri $guid {
     default "unknown";
     ~^/out/v\d+/(?P<id>.+?)/.+$ $id;
  }

  map $http_x_forwarded_for $last_client_ip {
     default $http_x_forwarded_for;
     ~,\s*(?P<last_ip>[\.\d]+?)\s*$ $last_ip;
  }

  limit_req_zone $guid zone=content:20m rate=500r/s;
  limit_req_zone $guid zone=auth:20m rate=100r/s;

  server {

    location /out/ {
      auth_request       /auth;

      set $request_type  "unknown";

      proxy_pass         $upstream_server;
      proxy_cache        content_cache;
      set $cache_key "${request_path}";
      proxy_cache_key    $cache_key;
      proxy_cache_valid  200 301 302  10s;

      #Throttling
      limit_req zone=content burst=50 nodelay;
      limit_req_status 429;
    }

    location /auth {
      internal;

      set $auth_type 1;
      proxy_pass_request_body off;
      proxy_pass         $upstream_server/auth?id=$guid&requestor=$last_client_ip;

      proxy_cache        auth_cache;
      set $auth_cache_key "${guid}|${last_client_ip}";
      proxy_cache_key    $auth_cache_key;
      proxy_cache_valid  200 301 302  5m;
      proxy_cache_valid  401 403 404  5m;

      #Throttling
      limit_req zone=auth burst=50 nodelay;
      limit_req_status 429;
    }
  }
}
```

The request limits on `/out/` work just as I would expected - requests in excess of 500r/s get throttled.  However, I don't seem to be able to get the `/auth` throttling to kick in.

I'm guessing this might be due to some interplay between `auth_request` and `limit_req`, or perhaps due to the fact that the `/auth` request are subrequests.  I would appreciate any help or explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an explanation of this behavior from the Nginx mailing list:

> The limit_req directive doesn't try to limit requests already limited,
>   as well as subrequests within these requests. You should configure all
>   limits you want to apply to a request in one place.

(See https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,280554,280558#msg-280558)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with the variable you use as **key**: $guid. This is not an nginx variable and sadly your snippet does not show how you define it. But the way you pass it to your proxy lets me suspect that every request to /auth has a different $guid. And then you will never run into the limit because nginx counts the requests per key, see here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

So if the $guid is not set at all for /out/, then all requests are counted towards the limit. No problem. But if it is indeed different for each request to /auth, then it won't work.

Comment: The `$guid` should uniquely identify a particular resource, and all of the requests for that resource should have the same `$guid`.  That variable seems to be set correctly since the auth cache also uses it as a key, and the cache is behaving as expected.

Comment: I've updated the snippet to show where `$guid` comes from.

Comment: @JaredStewart, for requests matching this regex `~^/out/v\d+/(?P<id>.+?)/.+$`, $guid indeed specifies the requested ressource. But for requests that ask for /auth, the regex does not match and $guid is "unknown" for all those. That _shouldnt_ be a problem but since this is the most obvious difference between the two I would try and use $binary_remote_addr as the key for the second limit_req_zone. Since /auth does not query a specific ressource, I think it is better to limit by client for those anyways.